# List of items placed inside a Swing environment

Tags: java, swing

Hello i have a simple program that has a toolbar with furniture jbuttons and a placing area. I am cloning buttons from my toolbar and placing them inside my other panel. It is a room floor sketcher. What im trying to do is have a list of items i have placed so far.

I have a method to add my node to the board:

```
  nodes.add(n);

  if(n instanceof OvenNode){
     ovens.add(n);
     System.out.println("added a oven");


     ov++;
     oven = "Oven x";
     map.put("Oven", ov);
     oven += map.get("Oven");
     shoppingList.add(oven);
  }
  else if(n instanceof FridgeNode){
     fridges.add(n);
     System.out.println("added a fridge");
     shoppingList.add("Fridge");
     fr++;
     map.put("Fridge", fr);
  }
```

And what i have tried so far is just creating an arraylist called shoppinglist and everytime i add a OvenNode it also adds a String Oven to the shopping list. There are other furniture peaces that also get added the same way

Then i have a method that turns that list into a string:

```
public String ListtoString(List<String> listen){

  String list = "";

  for (int i = 0; i < listen.size();i++) {

     String everything = listen.get(i).toString();

     list += everything  + " " + "\n";

  }

  return list;

}
```

This method together with ..

```
public List<String> shoppingList(){
  return shoppingList;
}
```

.. are called in:

```
  JMenuItem shoppingList = new JMenuItem("Shopping List");
  shoppingList.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        text = new JTextArea(graph.ListtoString(graph.shoppingList()));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                          text);

     }

  });
```

And this is where my list is.

But it looks like this:

[image: Result]

And I don't want it to be like this, I only want it to change the number and let the text be alone. So if there are 3 ovens and I add another one I should only increment the oven counter so it only has Oven x (the number that is incremented)

Is there something I can do in my `ListtoString` method like a substring so it cuts out the text part and only leaves the changing integer?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. 3) Please carefully review the formatted question as it appears below the input area, while being written or during [edit]. It should have been obvious it was not formatted as hoped.

Comment: As an aside. I would not use a list for this task, but a `JTable` with 2 columns. The columns would be item and count. It would have a single row for each type of item, initially with a count of 0. Use a [`TableRowSorter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html) (which also provides functionality to filter rows) to filter out the rows with 0 count.

Comment: Thank you i will try redoing this with a JTable!

Answer (score -1):

So i worked on it and came up with a solution that might not be the cleanest one but at least it works:

`  public String getmeList(){

```
  String ovs = "Ovens x";

  ovs += ov;

  String space = "\n";

  String fri = "Fridges x";

  fri += fr;

  String tot = "\n";

  String tab = "Tables x";

  tab += ta;

  String bedz = "Bed x";

  bedz += be;

  String cotop = "Countertop x";

  cotop += sp;

  String win = "Window x";

  win += wi;

  String war = "Wardrobe x";

  war += wa;
```

tot += ovs += space  += fri += space += tab += space += bedz += space += cotop += space += win += space += war;
      return tot;`

and now it i get this [image: result]

it also works very well when i remove something, because i only decrement the counter in my remove method.

cheers